# How to filter Firebase class before putting it into recyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using an addChildEventListener on the `users` level of my firebase database which contains `usernames` `email` and `latest_post`. The recyclerView will only use `latest_post` which is optional and not all users will have it, so I need to filter the userPosts object so that it contains only the users that have the field `latest_post'. here is the event listener:

```
 query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            User userPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            System.out.println("User" + userPost.getUsername());

        }
```

This is how I setUp the recyclerView cells:

```
void setPost(final User user) {

        final Post post = user.getLatest_post();

        final Long date = post.post_date;
        final String post_id = post.getPost_id();
        final String key = post.getPost_id();
        final Integer reads = post.getReads();
        final String titleString = post.getTitle();
        final String bodyString = post.getBody();
        final String usernameString = post.getAuthor();
        final String category = post.getCategory();
        final String author_id = post.getAuthor_id();

...

}
```

So unless I filter userPosts before I setUp the view it will crash because it will try even on the paths where there is no `latest_post`. How can I filter so that the object I use when setting up the recycler view only contains objects where `latest_post` is not null? I cannot change the database structure as this point. Thank you.

UPDATE:

By doing this I can see that It knows which values have latest_post and which don't, but im still not sure how to make it into a nice object I can do my setup with. I've updated the code like so:

```
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

            Post latestPost = dataSnapshot.child("latest_post").getValue(Post.class);
            Boolean userPost = dataSnapshot.hasChild("latest_post");

            System.out.println("User" + userPost);
            System.out.println("latestPost" + latestPost);
        }
```

So somehow I can just use the Post class contained in User:

```
    void setPost(final Post post) {

        final Post latest = post;

        final Long date = latest.post_date;
        final String post_id = latest.getPost_id();
        final String key = latest.getPost_id();
        final Integer reads = latest.getReads();
        final String titleString = latest.getTitle();
        final String bodyString = latest.getBody();
        final String usernameString = latest.getAuthor();
        final String category = latest.getCategory();
        final String author_id = latest.getAuthor_id();

...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, it turns out you can order a query, for example:

```
query = query.child("users").orderByChild("latest_post")
```

This would allow the recycled view to work but once you scroll to a certain point, it would crash.

You cannot filter a query to exclude items that don't exist.

I had to create my own recycler adapter, and use a list of my post class, and then filter that list after querying the database.